# Kubernetes eks supported HPA api version

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Does anyone know if eks 1.15 supports apps/v1 api for hpa scalling?

We have 2 environments and would like to keep the helm repo updated to both code versions

Comment: Have you tried to execute `kubectl api-versions` on your EKS 1.15 to see the available API versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand the difference between [Platform versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/platform-versions.html):

> Amazon EKS platform versions represent the capabilities of the cluster
> control plane, such as which Kubernetes API server flags are enabled,
> as well as the current Kubernetes patch version.

and [Kubernetes versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html):

> The Kubernetes project is rapidly evolving with new features, design
> updates, and bug fixes. The community releases new Kubernetes minor
> versions, such as 1.18, as generally available approximately every
> three months, and each minor version is supported for approximately
> twelve months after it is first released.

There are no specific [HPA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html) versions for EKS. You should rather check it from the Kubernetes side. To list the API versions that are available you can execute:

```
kubectl api-versions
```

or:

```
for kind in `kubectl api-resources | tail +2 | awk '{ print $1 }'`; do kubectl explain $kind; done | grep -e "KIND:" -e "VERSION:"
```

to list all the resource types with their latest supported API version.

There are currently two API [versions supported for HPA in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#api-object):

- The current stable version, which only includes support for CPU autoscaling, can be found in the `autoscaling/v1` API version.
- The beta version, which includes support for scaling on memory and custom metrics, can be found in `autoscaling/v2beta2`. The new fields introduced in autoscaling/v2beta2 are preserved as annotations when working with autoscaling/v1.

Also, a [kubectl convert](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#convert) might be useful to you if you wish to convert files between different API versions.

Comment: @DNDN Does the above solve your issue.